# MAAS issue with IPMI

Tags: dell, juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to enroll 4 Dell R720 Servers that utilize IPMI in the IDRAC.

I am able to enroll two of them without issue and they commission without error.

The other two which are set up the same exact way, boot up, get listed in MAAS, then powered down.  It then errors out trying to connect to the IDRAC to control the power.

I have verified that CLI access to the IDRAC is working just fine and have reset both systems and the IDRAC's, but nothing seems to work.